# Is there any way to find out which node has been used by SELECT statement in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, database-trigger, spark-cassandra-connector

I have written a custom LoadBalancerPolicy for `spark-cassandra-connector` and now I want to ensure that it really works!

I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and a keyspace with a replication factor of 2, so when we want to retrieve a record, there will be only two nodes on cassandra which hold the data.

The thing is that I want to ensure the `spark-cassandra-connector` (with my load-balancer-policy) is still token-aware and will choose the right node as coordinator for each "SELECT" statement.

Now, I'm thinking if we can write a trigger on the SELECT statement for each node, in case of the node does not hold the data, the trigger will create a log and I realize the load-balancer-policy does not work properly. How can we write a trigger On SELECT in Cassandra? Is there any better way to accomplish that?

I already checked the documentation for creating the triggers and those are too limited:

[Official documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/triggers.html)

[Documentation at DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html)

[Example implementation in official repo](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what Alex said, we can do it as below:

After creating SparkSession, we should make a connector:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
val connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf)
```

Now we can define a preparedStatement and do the rest:

```
connector.withSessionDo(session => {

    val selectQuery = "select * from test where id=?"
    val prepareStatement = session.prepare(selectQuery)
    val protocolVersion = session.getCluster.getConfiguration.getProtocolOptions.getProtocolVersion
    // We have to explicitly bind the all of parameters that partition key is based on them, otherwise the routingKey will be null.
    val boundStatement = prepareStatement.bind(s"$id")
    val routingKey = boundStatement.getRoutingKey(protocolVersion, null)
    // We can get tha all of nodes that contains the row
    val replicas = session.getCluster.getMetadata.getReplicas("test", routingKey)
    val resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement)

    // We can get the node which gave us the row
    val host = resultSet.getExecutionInfo.getQueriedHost

    // Final step is to check whether the replicas contains the host or not!!!
    if (replicas.contains(host)) println("It works!")
  })
```

The important thing is that we have to explicitly bind the all of parameters that partition key is based on them (i.e. we cannot set them har-codded in the SELECT statement), otherwise the routingKey will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the program side, if you [get routing key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html#getRoutingKey-com.datastax.driver.core.ProtocolVersion-com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry-) for your bound statement (you must use prepared statements), find the [replicas for it via Metadata class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getReplicas-java.lang.String-java.nio.ByteBuffer-), and then compare if [this host is in the ExecutionInfo](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.8/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getQueriedHost--) that you can get from `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thanks. It works, I just give another response with more details.